# Modify AppleIRController to enable/disable IR controller using AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I'm looking to enable and disable the IR using AppleScript. I'm following the example [here](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=27226). The code successfully updates the checkmark in System Preferences, but it doesn't actually enable (or disable) the IR receiver. Any suggestions?